# DD-WRT Port Forwarding Issues

Tags: port-forwarding, nat, dd-wrt

I have set up a Linksys WRT-3200ACM router with DD-WRT (v3.0-r39956 std (06/06/19)) behind a FritzBox 7430 router. The FritzBox acts as modem to connect to a standard DSL line. The Linksys router is set as exposed host (DMZ, I guess?) and is allowed to make its own port forwardings.

What I would like to do, is forward external requests from port 80 to my webserver (behind the Linksys router) listening on port 80. What I have got working, is connecting to the Linksys router itself from the WAN (By entering my WAN IP I am redirected to the status page of the router, I guess this is default behaviour).

AFAIK, the only step left is setting up a port forward (on the Linksys router) like this:
[image: port forward]

However, this doesn't seem to work? I am always redirected to the Linksys status page, it is as if the forwarding does not have any effect. This applies when accessing my public IP from the WAN and from within the LAN. I suspect it has something to do with the fact, that the Linksys router is behind the FritzBox (but why does default access work flawlessly?). I have DDNS set up on the Linksys which also works as expected:

[image: DDNS]
When trying to access my webserver from the WAN, both the public IP and the URL redirect to the routers status page. I have tried to redirect to other hosts in the network, to test if the issue was in fact something with the webserver. But IMO, even *if* the webserver would block the connection (firewall etc.), I would simply get an error message instead of being redirected to the routers status page.

Here is the basic IP setup:

```
[WAN IP] FritzBox [10.0.1.10] --------------- [10.0.1.21] Linksys [10.0.0.10] 
                                                                   | [10.0.0.1] Webserver
```

Unfortunatly, I cannot remove the FritzBox (not even temporarily) from the network as my provider does not provide username/password for PPPoE connections anymore.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, leaving the SourceNet *empty* solves the problem:

[image: Powert forwading]

I do not know why this solves the problem, but it does.

Answer (score -1):

Linksys listen ports cannot be the port that you are trying to forward.
Change your Linksys management port to something other than 80. Ex. 8080.

Comment: no, that doesn't solve the problem. And I know that I have forwarded port80 before.

Comment: However, it is noteworthy, that when changing the port forward from listening port 80 to 90, and accessing <WAN_IP>:90 the router page is not shown, instead the adress simply cannot be reached.